# Can I use this power supply + case combination without causing problems?

Tags: power-supply, case

I am putting together a computer with a Antec P180 case and a Thermaltake TR2 RX 650 W power supply.

The problem is that the Antec P180 case has a separate compartment for the power supply. With an opening for the on/off switch + ac connector to one side, a wall with a small hole for cables to route through on top, a wall on the bottom, and on the other side a fan which pushes air from the hard drive compartment to the power supply compartment.

I think the design of the case assumes the power supplies fan is on the side next to the on/off switch, but the fan on the power supply I have is on top, which makes me worry about overheating the power supply. There is about half an inch between the top of the power supply and the wall and the other fan should keep air flowing to push out the air that the power supply pushes upwards.

Do you think this setup should work, or should I go get another power supply?

Thanks!!

PS: This computer will be running an Ubuntu server, so it will always be on, but the rest of the components shouldn't be generating as much heat as they would on say a gaming machine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Antec P180 case and had this concern as well.  The question is answered on Antec's website FAQ:

http://www.antec.com/index.php?page=support_roductInfo_FAQ&FAQno=21

> **Questions:**
> My power supply has a fan on the bottom. How should I mount it in the case?
>
> **Answers:**
> The bottom-mounted fan should be pointed towards the top of the enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

On all standard ATX PSU's the fans are intake. So long as the fan in the case is configured to blow into the PSU compartment it should compliment the PSU's fan rather than hinder it.